# C allocation memory error. Don't find something like this

Tags: c, loops, malloc, c-strings

Could you help please ? 
When I execute this code I receive that: 
AAAAABBBBBCCCCCBBBBBCOMP¬ıd┐╔ LENGTH 31
There are some weirds characters after letters, while I've allocate just 21 bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char * lineDown(){
    unsigned short state[4] = {0,1,2,1};
    char decorationUp[3][5] = {
        {"AAAAA"},{"BBBBB"},{"CCCCC"}
    };
    char * deco = malloc(21);
    int k;
    int p = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        k = state[j];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
           *(deco+p) = decorationUp[k][i];
           p++;
        }
    }
    return deco;
}
int main(void){

    char * lineDOWN = lineDown();
    int k = 0;
    char c;
    do{
        c = *(lineDOWN+k);
        printf("%c",*(lineDOWN+k));
        k++;
    }while(c != '\0');
    printf("LENGTH %d\n\n",k);
}
```

Comment: you missed the ending null char in strings, in `char decorationUp[3][5] = {` 5 must be 6, else you have an undefined behavior. YOU can also let the compiler to decide the needed sizes

Comment: you know that `*(ptr + index)` can also be written as `ptr[index]`... `*(deco+p) = decorationUp[k][i];` same as `deco[p] = decorationUp[k][i];`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In

```
char decorationUp[3][5] = {
    {"AAAAA"},{"BBBBB"},{"CCCCC"}
};
```

your string needs 6 characters to also place the null char, even in that case you do not use them as 'standard' string but only array of char. To get into the habit always reverse the place for the ending null character

you can do

```
char decorationUp[3][6] = {
    {"AAAAA"},{"BBBBB"},{"CCCCC"}
};
```

Note it is useless to give the first size, the compiler counts for you

Because in *main* you stop when you read the null character you also need to place it in *deco* at the end, so you need to allocate 21 for it. As before you missed the place for the null character, but here that produces an undefined behavior because you read after the allocated block.

To do `*(deco+p)` is not readable, do `deco[p]`

So for instance :

```
char * lineDown(){
    unsigned short state[] = {0,1,2,1};
    char decorationUp[][6] = {
        {"AAAAA"},{"BBBBB"},{"CCCCC"}
    };
    char * deco = malloc(4*5 + 1); /* a formula to explain why 21 is better than 21 directly */
    int k;
    int p = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        k = state[j];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
           deco[p] = decorationUp[k][i];
           p++;
        }
    }
    deco[p] = 0;
    return deco;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function does not build a string because the result array does not contain the terminating zero though a space for it was reserved when the array was allocated.

```
char * deco = malloc(21);
```

So you need to append the array with the terminating zero before exiting the function

```
    //... 
    *(deco + p ) = '\0';

    return deco;
}
```

Otherwise this do-while loop

```
do{
    c = *(lineDOWN+k);
    printf("%c",*(lineDOWN+k));
    k++;
}while(c != '\0')
```

will have undefined behavior.

But even if you will append the array with the terminating zero the loop will count the length of the stored string incorrectly because it will increase the variable k even when the current character is the terminating zero.

Instead you should use a while loop. In this case the declaration of the variable `c` will be redundant. The loop can look like

```
while ( *( lineDOWN + k ) )
{
    printf("%c",*(lineDOWN+k));
    k++;
}
```

In this case this call

```
printf("\nLENGTH %d\n\n",k);
        ^^
```

will output the correct length of the string equal to `20`.

And you should free the allocated memory before exiting the program

```
free( lineDOWN );
```

As some other wrote here in their answers that the array `decorationUp` must be declared like

```
char decorationUp[3][6] = {
    {"AAAAA"},{"BBBBB"},{"CCCCC"}
};
```

then it is not necessary if you are not going to use elements of the array as strings and you are not using them as strings in your program.

Take into account that your program is full of magic numbers. Such a program is usually error-prone. Instead you should use named constants.